# windows phone change deactivated app image

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

For security purposes I wanna change app's image when it is in deactivated state(i.e. when START button is pressed).

Currently it shows the current page image from which START button is pressed. I don't want the data on the page to be revealed.

Comment: What image do you mean? the tile for the app or the screenshot used on the multitasking menu (press and hold the Back key) ?

Comment: Yes Yes i mean the screenshot image on the multitasking menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is **No**.

There is no API for manipulating the image that's generated for the multitasking menu (ie. recently used apps).

Although it's possible to manipulate Back button navigation within an app, when a user presses the Start button on their phone, there is no way to delay or cancel that event.

And when a `Navigating` event occurs, it doesn't appear to be possible to update the UI or screen in time (the update may happen after the app resumes).